# How to convert a PNG to BGR 565 format using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use Image Magick to convert a PNG file into a BGR 565 bitmap image.  I've done a fair amount of research and haven't been able to come up with an answer. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Maybe posting what you have tried so far with a more specific question would be helpful.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried anything that got me anywhere close (not much experience working with image transformation), which is why I intentionally left it broad.  I figured a large array of different answers would not only help solve my problem but also give me a better background understanding of how the transformation worked (the answer below helps clarify what's actually happening)

Comment: I would suggest reading the help center for why your question was put on hold. It's ALWAYS a good idea to put some effort into doing your own research before posting on Stack Overflow and trying things on your own.

Comment: Like him, it's incredibly hard to find a software that does this translation : RGB 888 --> BGR 565.

So I made a little software in 10min , starting from the answer of  
Glenn Randers-Pehrson.


Check it out here : https://github.com/bestel74/Raw-Image-Translator

Comment: @user2629409 Thanks.  But see http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/may-someone-else-apply-a-license-to-cc0-material/4912#4912

Comment: I'm sorry Glenn, I update my project. I was upset, but now I just think I need to learn the "good manner" in open-source. Tell me if what I do now is ok. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I left a comment on the commit at github.  I think what you have now is a little excessive; all that's really needed is the one-line attribution in the body of the program.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile this C program and install it in your search path as "rgbtobgr565"

```
/* rgbtobgr565 - convert 24-bit RGB pixels to 16-bit BGR565 pixels

  Written in 2016 by Glenn Randers-Pehrson <glennrp@users.sf.net>

  To the extent possible under law, the author has dedicated all copyright
  and related and neighboring rights to this software to the public domain
  worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.
  See <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>. 

  Use with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to convert 24-bit RGB pixels
  to 16-bit BGR565 pixels, e.g.,

      magick file.png -depth 8 rgb:- | rgbtobgr565 > file.bgr565

  Note that the 16-bit pixels are written in network byte order (most
  significant byte first), with blue in the most significant bits and
  red in the least significant bits.

  ChangLog:
  Jan 2017: changed bgr565 from int to unsigned short (suggested by
             Steven Valsesia)
*/

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int red,green,blue;
    unsigned short bgr565;
    while (1) {
        red=getchar(); if (red == EOF) return (0);
        green=getchar(); if (green == EOF) return (1);
        blue=getchar(); if (blue == EOF) return (1);
        bgr565 = (unsigned short)(red * 31.0 / 255.0) |
                 (unsigned short)(green * 63.0 / 255.0) << 5 |
                 (unsigned short)(blue * 31.0 / 255.0) << 11;
            putchar((bgr565 >> 8) & 0xFF);
            putchar(bgr565 & 0xFF);
        }
    }
```

Then run

```
magick file.png -depth 8 rgb:- | rgbtobgr565 > file.bgr565
```

For completeness, here is the program for converting bgr565 pixels back to rgb:

```
/* bgr565torgb - convert 16-bit BGR565 pixels to 24-bit RGB pixels

  Written in 2016 by Glenn Randers-Pehrson <glennrp@users.sf.net>

  To the extent possible under law, the author has dedicated all copyright
  and related and neighboring rights to this software to the public domain
  worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.
  See <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>. 

  Use with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to convert 16-bit BGR565 pixels
  to 24-bit RGB pixels, e.g.,

      bgr565torgb < file.bgr565 > file.rgb
      magick -size WxH -depth 8 file.rgb file.png 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int rgbhi,rgblo,red,green,blue;
    while (1) {
        rgbhi=getchar(); if (rgbhi == EOF) return (0);
        rgblo=getchar(); if (rgblo == EOF) return (1);
        putchar((rgblo & 0x1F) << 3 | (rgblo & 0x14) >> 3 );
        putchar((rgbhi & 0x07) << 5 |
                (rgblo & 0xE0) >> 3 |
                (rgbhi & 0x06) >> 1);
        putchar((rgbhi & 0xE0) | (rgbhi >> 5) & 0x07);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer even if other folks don't like the question ;-)

Comment: Thanks this gives a lot of clarity.  Is it possible to do this in one `convert` command instead of using a pipe to another method? As solid as this answer is, it would be difficult to implement this using an image magick libary in a server.

Comment: It would require a modification to ImageMagick (a similar amount of code as shown here).  Or, it's likely possible to install the "rgbtobgr565" program as a delegate on your server; I'll look into that.

Comment: @user2629429 I agree that bgr565 should be unsigned short. Red, green, blue, rgbhi, and rgblo have to be int so getchar() will properly return EOF.  I've updated the program accordingly; see the embedded ChangeLog.